# How to remove the one letter spacing after footnotetext command?

Tags: spacing, equations, footnotes

Here's a problem confused me for long time, the minimal executable code is listed below:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{equation*}
        A = B\cap C\footnotemark
    \end{equation*}
    \footnotetext{\lipsum[1]}
    orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.  Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

the generated result is:

[image]

look at the marked area by red color, I find that if I use `\footnotetext{}`, it would generate about half letter spacing at the beginning of the next line, whereas there's no spacing if I directly use `\footnote{}`. However, `\footnote{}` is only useful in `equation` or `equation*` environment. I've test for many times, I'm sure it's a spacing.

My question is How to remove the small spacing after `\footnotetext{}`?

Comment: You need a `%` at the end of this line: `\footnotetext{\lipsum[1]}%`. Otherwise, you introduce a stray space. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Comment: Also, you should not have a blank line before the `equation`, as it adversely messes with the vertical spacing.

Comment: I would probably never place a footnote inside or attached to anything math related as it can be misunderstood by the reader.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  A problem you haven't mentioned is the loss of the letter "o" from "orem".  ("L" was already absent from the input text, which leads me to believe that the syntax required by `\footnotetext` isn't correct.)  If only the extra space was the problem, that could likely be corrected by inserting a `%` sign at the end of the preceding line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The missing letter is due to the footnote text being `\lipsum[1]`. Curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think twice before footnoting an equation, because the footnote marker will be most likely be confused with an exponent.

Anyway, the space you see is the effect of the endline after `\footnotetext{...}`

Fix it with a `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
  A = B\cap C\footnotemark
\end{equation*}
\footnotetext{A footnote}% <--- HERE!
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The missing first letter in your picture is a curious side effect of `\lipsum[1]` in the footnote text.

[image]

Note that there is no `UTF8` option to the document class. Remove it.

Comment: thanks for your solution and `UTF8` advice, it works perfectly.